# How to partition a Free Space using parted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, parted

During the installation of my ubuntu server, I had to leave a big space of my hard drive for specific service. Well, I forgot to to partition it up and leave it mounted during installation. Right Now, I realized I won't be able to use it without being partitioned.

```
(parted) print free
 Model: DELL PERC 6/i (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sda: 292GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: msdos

 Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
         32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
  1      1049kB  500MB   499MB   primary   ext2            boot
  2      500MB   26.3GB  25.8GB  primary   ext3
         26.3GB  26.3GB  1048kB            Free Space
  3      26.3GB  32.3GB  5999MB  extended
  5      26.3GB  32.3GB  5999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
         32.3GB  292GB   260GB             Free Space
```

What I'mmona need to do, is partition that indicated "Free Space" as well as mount it on a certain /dev/sd* device in order to use it.
Any help with that?

Comment: Do you want to create new partition on the "260Gb Free Space" and have it mounted every time, right?

Comment: Sorry I first advised you Gparted and the decided to ask it: do you need to partition namely by using parted?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov- Yes that's right, I want the 260GB not necessarily be formatted but mounted to a device like /dev/sd* so I'd be able to use it. FYI, I'm not using GUI linux.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into into `fdisk` instead of `parted`.

Personally I use [fdisk](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html) when it comes to raw partitioning without [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm), because I find it slimmer than `parted`. But that is only personal preference.

Anyways `fdisk` is pretty straightforward. Just type `fdisk` an once you have the `fdisk` promt press `m`. The rest ist self explanatory I think. If you need guidance see the link to the TLDP, that should guide you through the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a new partition install and run Gparted,

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: Oh, Gparted is a GUI tool for GNOME based systems. I'm only using linux server without GUI. That's why I'm looking for appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still no proper answer

How to make partition from free space at the end of disk.

- add partition on free space at the end of disk

1. Look around in our disks ( CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009, parted (GNU parted) 3.1 )

```
[root@test-vm ~]# parted /dev/sda print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 161GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
        32,3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  ext4            boot
 2      525MB   51,6GB  51,1GB  primary  ext4
 3      51,6GB  53,7GB  2097MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
        53,7GB  161GB   107GB            Free Space
```

2. We see our client `53,7GB  161GB   107GB            Free Space`.
   Make partition with oneliner

```
[root@test-vm ~]# parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 53,7GB 161GB
# or parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 53,7GB 100%
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

3. Check it

```
[root@test-vm ~]# parted /dev/sda print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 161GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
        32,3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  ext4            boot
 2      525MB   51,6GB  51,1GB  primary  ext4
 3      51,6GB  53,7GB  2097MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 4      53,7GB  161GB   107GB   primary
```

4. That is it. After it you can add it to LVM or just create filesystem on it.
5. On later versions of `parted` ( parted (GNU parted) 3.3
   ) and systems like `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS` output differs ( there is no Type table, but syntax the same)

```
oot@ubuntu:~# parted /dev/vda print free
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
14      1049kB  5243kB  4194kB                     bios_grub
15      5243kB  116MB   111MB   fat32              boot, esp
 1      116MB   10.0GB  9884MB  ext4
        10.0GB  21.5GB  11.5GB  Free Space

root@ubuntu:~# parted /dev/vda mkpart primary ext4 10.0GB 21.5GB
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

root@ubuntu:~# parted /dev/vda print free
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
14      1049kB  5243kB  4194kB                        bios_grub
15      5243kB  116MB   111MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 1      116MB   10.0GB  9884MB  ext4
        10.0GB  10.0GB  269kB   Free Space
 2      10.0GB  21.5GB  11.5GB               primary
        21.5GB  21.5GB  1032kB  Free Space
```

Comment: Already four years ago there was an answer, saying that `parted` is old and can be replaced by `fdisk`. So why this answer?